# ERROR running force:package:version:create: No matching source was found within the package root directory

Tags: salesforcedx-cli, unlocked-package, versioning

I'm trying to update an unmanaged package that I've been developing and am running into the following error when running the following command:

`sfdx force:package:version:create -p SomePackage -d force-app -k test1234 --wait 10 -v myclient-prod --codecoverage`

`No matching source was found within the package root directory: C:\Users\someuser\Dropbox\vscode_workspace\myclient\force-app`

I tried reverting to a previous version of sfdx-cli, verifying that I have source in the correct paths, etc. I also reverted to a version that a user said worked for him here: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9062I000000IWlmQAG, but that didn't help. I uninstalled & reinstalled, no luck. I have been able to create new versions in the past, so I don't think it's a config issue.

Just in case, here's my sfdx-config:

```
    "packageDirectories": [
        {
            "path": "force-app",
            "default": true,
            "package": "SomePackage",
            "versionName": "ver 0.1",
            "versionNumber": "0.1.9.NEXT"
        }
    ],
    "namespace": "",
    "sfdcLoginUrl": "https://login.salesforce.com",
    "sourceApiVersion": "51.0",
    "packageAliases": {
        "SomePackage": "0Ho4x0000...",
        "SomePackage@0.1.1": "04t...",
        "SomePackage@0.1.2-1": "04t4x0000...",
        "SomePackage@0.1.3-1": "04t4x0000...",
        "SomePackage@0.1.4-1": "04t4x0000...",
        "SomePackage@0.1.5-1": "04t4x00...",
        "SomePackage@0.1.6-1": "04t4x...",
        "SomePackage@0.1.6-2": "04t4x0..AO",
        "SomePackage@0.1.7-1": "04t4x0000...",
        "SomePackage@0.1.8-1": "04t4x00...",
        "SomePackage@0.1.8-2": "04t4x000..."
    }
}
```

Based on one of the comments below, I'm adding my .forceignore:

```
# List files or directories below to ignore them when running force:source:push, force:source:pull, and force:source:status
# More information: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_exclude_source.htm
#

package.xml

# LWC configuration files
**/jsconfig.json
**/.eslintrc.json

# LWC Jest
**/__tests__/**

ProductServiceCampaignItem.My_ProductServiceCampaignItems
ProductServiceCampaignItem.My_RecentProductServiceCampaignItems
ProductServiceCampaignItem.All_ProductServiceCampaignItems
ShiftTemplate.My_RecentShiftTemplates
ShiftTemplate.My_ShiftTemplates
ShiftTemplate.All_ShiftTemplates

**/prompts/**
```

I don't see anything there that should prevent this from running. Does anyone else?

[image: ls force-app/main/default]

Comment: I wonder: are you allowed to create patch versions for unmanaged packages?

Comment: @PhilW Thanks for the comment. Yes, it's possible. Note the previous versions in the sfdx-config file.

Comment: Great. I only asked since I know 2GP is like 1GP for managed packages- you can only create patch releases for security reviewed packages.

Comment: can you try same from CLI(not going to VS code at all). Ideally it should initiate the process for creating package. There may be some issues occur, but not this particular issue.

Comment: @YsrShk  I tried from a standalone Windows Powershell and got the same error. ls force-app give main, ls main gives default and ls default gives the whole dir - animationRules, aura, classes, customMetadata, etc.

Comment: ideally normal force-app folder shall work fine. Unless there is different folder structure opted. And from config json, it should use force-app only. It seems sfdx cli issue. need to do some trial n error with versions.

Comment: Have you checked your .forceignore?  If you have  v7.94.3 or newer of the CLI installed, you can run `sfdx force:source:ignored:list` to see what files are being ignored.

Comment: @JasonClark I can't run this, even though I'm on 7.94.3-a4e7c7955b. However, I pasted my .forceignore file in above. Do you think anything there would prevent the cli from finding my project?

Comment: It should not matter, but I'd try removing/commenting `package.xml`.  That's the only thing I see in your .forceignore that I wonder about.  You might also try explicitly specifying your scratch def (e.g., `--definitionfile config/project-scratch-def.json`); it is used during version creation to spin up a scratch and run tests for coverage.  Finally, if none of the above works, try running with --json, in case the json-formatted output includes additional error information.

Comment: @JasonClark thanks so much for having a look! Neither of these helped. Any other ideas?

Comment: I had the very same problem when I messed up with my folders. Can you execute "ls C:\Users\someuser\Dropbox\vscode_workspace\myclient\force-app" or display what is content of C:\Users\someuser\Dropbox\vscode_workspace\myclient\force-app folder?

Comment: Thanks @Patlatus. ls force-app give main, ls main gives default, and I'm uploading the screenshot of force-app/main/default

Comment: Could you please specify in which folder are you executing the script sfdx force:package:version:create  and which is content of sfdx-project.json? Does it coinside with the listing you provided? If "force-app" the correct relative path from that folder?

Comment: Few ideas
1. Re-install from scratch your SFDX CLI to the latest version 
2. You can try to force the command to look into the directory by adding a second entry on sfdx-project.json: 
```
,
    {
      "path": "temp/force-app",
      "default": false
    }
```
3. I think there might be some sort of conflict with flags -d and -p, can you try to completely leave out the -d flag in your command?

Comment: @Patlatus I'm running it in force-app.

Comment: @imTachu I've tried all of those steps.

Comment: Hi, you should not be running the command in force-app, but in the root dir, above force-app.